# How Can I Model Demand Elasticity?

Tags: utility, supply-and-demand, finance, elasticity, demand

Can demand elasticity be determined by examining the distribution of marginal utility across a potential customer base?
For example, if the distribution of marginal utility among potential customers had, on average, a relatively high derivative, can we infer that the demand elasticity would be high? Or are there other factors which influence demand elasticity?

Comment: 1. How would you measure marginal utility? Do you maybe mean willingness to pay?

Comment: 2. "*relatively high derivative, can we infer that the demand elasticity would be high*" Derivative is scale dependent, elasticity is not.